# Using google calender inside greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use the google calender api inside a greasemonkey script. This is my code inspired from the google calender api tutorial:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Google Calender
// @namespace   xyz
// @include     *
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

API_js_callback = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = API_js_callback;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
(head || document.body).appendChild(script);

//this is not working
var gapi = unsafeWindow.gapi;


$(document).ready(function()
                  {
    // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    var CLIENT_ID = 'XXX';

    // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

    handleClientLoad();

    /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
    function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
    function initClient() {
     .........
    }
});
```

Inside the `handleClientLoad` method, I got the following exception:

```
Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
```

Any idea?

Comment: i can make it work from my side, maybe it's the loading time that block this variable, try to move `var gapi = unsafeWindow.gapi;` inside the function `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: I tried this but the gapi variable is still unfefined.

Comment: maybe you have to specify the `@include` with something like `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/*`

Comment: The @include says where the script should be executed (on which pages), not what should be included.

Comment: since this kind of pages loads a lot of subdomains, each one triggers the script, that's how i tested it

Answer (score 0):

The gapi library is injected after the document loads, therefore it hasn't loaded yet when the document is ready. The gapi-related code need to be run on script load, for example:

```
GAPI_js_src = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = GAPI_js_src;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
(head || document.body).appendChild(script);

script.onload = (function() {
    var gapi = unsafeWindow.gapi;
    // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    var CLIENT_ID = 'XXX';

    // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

    handleClientLoad();

    /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
    function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
    function initClient() {
     .........
    }
});
```